# Compare c# datetime in client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

im using asp.net mvc c#, im my example i need the user to enter a date and i will the check if the date that that user entered its between the from date and to date that i read it from the database then i will submit the form else alert should appear .

my razor view

```
  @foreach (var obj in Model)
    {
       <tr data-myLoop="loop">
          <td data-date="date"> @Html.DatePicker("myList[" + index + "].UserDate", 
           obj.InterviewDate) </td>

          <td class="hidden" data-fromDate="fromDate">
                @Html.Hidden("myList[" + index + "].FromDate", obj.FromDate)
          </td>
          <td class="hidden" data-toDate="toDate">
                 @Html.Hidden("myList[" + index + "].toDate", obj.toDate)
           </td> 
       </tr>

        index++;
    }
```

in java script :

```
$("[data-myLoop='loop']").each(function () {

var fromDate= $(this).find('[data-fromDate="fromDate"]').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
var ToDate= $(this).find('[data-toDate="toDate"]').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
var userDate = $(this).find('[data-date="date"]').datepicker('getDate');

if(userDate < fromDate || userDate > ToDate)
    alert("not in range");



});
```

But this comparasion is not always gives the expected result . i think because the type of fromDate and toDate is string in javascript not date.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all the string dates to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) object first using `new Date(string)` constructor before compare like:

```
var fromDate = new Date($(this).find('[data-fromDate="fromDate"]').find('input[type="hidden"]').val());
var ToDate = new Date($(this).find('[data-toDate="toDate"]').find('input[type="hidden"]').val());
var userDate = $(this).find('[data-date="date"]').datepicker('getDate');

if (userDate < fromDate || userDate > ToDate)
   alert("not in range");
```

Also, `.datepicker('getDate')` already returns a `Date` object, so we do not need to convert that again to a `Date` object again here.